# Convert Promise to Async Await

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I am converting different code snippets with promise functions into async await functions. VS Code can do it automatically, but in some places I have to do it manually as VS Code doesn't highlight the promise syntax. Could anybody show me one example of converting promise to async based on this expression?

```js
const getJson = url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json());

    getJson('/i/1.json')
    .then(json => {
        if (json.key) {
            return getJson('/i/2.json')
        }
        throw new Error('No key')
    })
    .then(json => {
        return json.key2
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
    })
```

Following this article https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-refactor-a-promise-chain-to-async-functions/
I guess I should get something like this:

```js
const getJson = url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json());

const getJson1 = await getJson();
const getJson2 = await getJson2(key);
const getJson3 = await getJson3(key2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
const getJson = async (url) => {
  const res = await fetch(url)
  return res.json()
}

const yourFetch = async () => {
  try {
    const json = await getJson('/i/1.json')
    
    if (json.key)  {
      const json2 = await getJson('/i/2.json')
      return json2.key
    }

    throw new Error('No key')
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`await` (besides Modules) is only valid inside an **async function**. So let's create an Async IIFE

```js
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
const getJson = async url => await fetch(url).then(res => res.json());

;(async () => { // Async IIFE
    
  const getJson1 = await getJson(`${url}/users/1`);
  if (!getJson1.id) throw new Error('No ID');
  const getJson2 = await getJson(`${url}/todos/${getJson1.id}`);
  console.log(getJson2);

})();

console.log("PS: I don't wait for the above to finish");
```

If you know the paths upfront you could go for [**Promise.all**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```js
const getJson = (url) => fetch(url).then(res => res.json());

Promise.all([
  getJson("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1"),
  getJson("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
]).then((res) => {
  console.log("Both are done!")
  console.log(res[0]);
  console.log(res[1]);
});
```

Comment: Top-level await is a thing, but there's caveats

Comment: @Evert Unless used in modules: https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await - AFAIK at this date there's no such thing as top-level await. Top level await will always throw an Error.

Comment: Your reply contradicts itself, but I think you got it.

Comment: @Evert than we understand each other. OP did not provided nor mentioned any use of JS Modules.